# trying to create a view by joining two tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join, sql-view

I am trying to run the following code:

```
create or replace view StoreContactPurchaseHistoryView AS
select
    STORE.StoreName,
    StoreContactAndPhone(contact,phone),
    PURCHASE_ITEM.PurchaseItemID,
    PURCHASE_ITEM.PurchaseDate,
    PURCHASE_ITEM.ItemDescription,
    PURCHASE_ITEM.PriceUSD
from 
    store,
    purchase_item
    
left join purchase_item on purchase_item.storeid=store.storeid
;
```

I keep getting this error:

> Error report -
>
> ORA-00904: "STORE"."STOREID": invalid identifier
>
> 904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Answer (score 2):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

That said, you want something like:

```
select s.StoreName, StoreContactAndPhone(contact, phone) as col,
       pi.PurchaseItemID, pi.PurchaseDate,
       pi.ItemDescription, pi.PriceUSD
from store s join
     purchase_item pi
     on pi.storeid = s.storeid;
```

Note that I also added table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.

Comment: ok so I tried: 

create or replace view StoreContactPurchaseHistoryView AS
select s.StoreName, StoreContactAndPhone(contact, phone),
       pi.PurchaseItemID, pi.PurchaseDate,
       pi.ItemDescription, pi.PriceUSD
from store s join
     purchase_item pi
    on pi.storeid = s.storeid;
and I keep getting this error: "must name this expression with a column alias"

Comment: @Snowflake22 . . . So give the column a name, presumably the function call.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing explicit and implicit joins, and seem to need only one join:

```
create or replace view StoreContactPurchaseHistoryView AS
select
    s.StoreName,
    StoreContactAndPhone(contact,phone),
    p.PurchaseItemID,
    p.PurchaseDate,
    p.ItemDescription,
    p.PriceUSD
from 
    store s
    left join purchase_item p on p.storeid = s.storeid
;
```

I used table aliases to shorten the query.

Side note: it is unclear what expression `StoreContactAndPhone(contact,phone)` actually refers to; I left it as-is in the query.

Comment: the expression StoreContactAndPhone(contact,phone) is a stored function, that concatenates two parameters in this case the contact and the phone number.

Comment: @Snowflake22: ok that make sense. You should at least alias the expression in the resultset (as commented by Gordon Linoff as well).

Answer (score 1):

Change it to this:

```
create or replace view StoreContactPurchaseHistoryView AS
select
    STORE.StoreName,
    StoreContactAndPhone(contact,phone),
    PURCHASE_ITEM.PurchaseItemID,
    PURCHASE_ITEM.PurchaseDate,
    PURCHASE_ITEM.ItemDescription,
    PURCHASE_ITEM.PriceUSD
from 
    store

left join purchase_item on purchase_item.storeid=store.storeid
;
```